# ¿Cómo obtengo el menor número de una lista mientras devuelvo también el resto de la lista en SWI-prolog?

Tags: lista, prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy tratado de hacer que este codigo me devuelva tanto el número más pequeño de la lista,"que lo hace cuando no explota" pero requiero de que también me devuelva la lista sin el susodicho menor elemento.
Alguien me puede indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias.

El codigo en cuestion ES:

```
/*Selec selec_min*/
list_min(M, [X|Xs],L):-
         list_min2(M, X, Xs,L).

list_min2(M, M, [],_).

list_min2(X, Y, [Z|Zs],_):-
          Z =< Y,
          list_min2(X, Z, Zs,Zs).

list_min2(X, Y, [Z|Zs],L):- 
          Z >= Y,conca(Z,Zs,L),
          list_min2(X, Y, Zs,L).

conca([X | L1], L2, [X | L3]):-
 conca(L1,L2,L3).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
my_list_min(X,[A],[]):- X is A.
my_list_min([X],List,Rest):- min_list(List,X), findall(Y,(member(Y,List),Y =\= X),Rest).
```

La lógica es la siguiente, si tu lista tiene un único elemento, ese es el menor y el resto es una lista vacía, ese es el caso base.

Para el resto unimos dos ideas, la primera que x es el mínimo valor de la lista.
La segunda, que lo que queda es la lista sin ese valor, así que buscamos todos los elementos que sean miembros de la lista y que no sean el menor agregando la capacidad de eliminar todos los duplicados del menor y quitarlos de el resto de la lista sin importar ne qué posición se encuentren.